# Python fastest way to return changed element from one list to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following code:

```
list_a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
list_b = [1,2,3,4,999,6,7,8]

for i in range(len(list_b)):
    if (list_a[i] != list_b[i]):
        print('The element in the original list has changed to: ' + str(list_b[i]))
```

My question: Is there a more efficient way to do this? The order of the numbers in both lists does not matter (however in this instance it is dependent on that); I just want to be able to return when an element from `list_a` has changed in `list_b`

EDIT: Factors that are ensured:

- Lists are ALWAYS the same length
- `List_b` will only change one element
  at a time

Some function:

```
return_change_in_list(list_a, list_b)
>>> '999'
```

Comment: list_a == list_b ??

Comment: for varying lengths you can use `itertools.zip_longest` but the algorithm you described is the same

Comment: @Vicrobot But I want to return the element that has changed in `list_b`

Comment: @KyleDeGennaro Can you update your question to reflect that? Because your current code does not return the element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Comment: @KyleDeGennaro there is no fancy algorithm that will make this faster than iterating through the lists in parallel. You may get a speedup from using `numpy` arrays over `list`s but it's really situation dependent.

Comment: Also *The order of the numbers in both lists does not matter*? That's inconsistent with that you've described in the problem.

Comment: @pault The order matters when I am iterating so I can return where a difference occurs. If I am checking two lists to see where an element changes the order should not matter.

Answer (score 1):

A method using a [list comprehension](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=list+comprehension+python&t=hp&ia=web), (which is not the best as I'll explain next):

```py
list_a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
list_b = [1,2,3,4,999,6,7,8]

result = [list_b[i] for i in range(len(list_b)) if list_a[i]!=list_b[i]]
if result:
  print("The element in the original list has changed to: %d." % result[0])
```

Output:

`The element in the original list has changed to: 999.`

Let's measure the run time of five different functions using [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) to find out which method is the fastest:

```py
import timeit

def return_change_in_list1(list_a, list_b):
  """function 1, similar to the presented in the question"""
  for i in range(len(list_b)):
    if (list_a[i] != list_b[i]):
      return list_b[i]

def return_change_in_list2(list_a, list_b):
  """function 2"""
  if list_a==list_b:
    return
  return [list_b[i] for i in range(len(list_b)) if list_a[i]!=list_b[i]][0]

def return_change_in_list3(list_a, list_b):
  """function 3"""
  result = [list_b[i] for i in range(len(list_b)) if list_a[i]!=list_b[i]]
  if result:
    return result[0]

def return_change_in_list4(list_a, list_b):
  """function 4, answer of Jab"""
  for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b):
    if a != b:
      return b

def return_change_in_list5(list_a, list_b):
  """function 5, answer of GZ0 and Jab"""
  return next((b for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b) if a != b), None)

list1 = [i for i in range(10000)]+[10001]+[i for i in range(10000)]  # I could also put list1=[i for i in range(10000)]+[10001]+[i for i in range(10001,20001)]...
list2 = [i for i in range(10000)]+[1]+[i for i in range(10000)]

print("function 1;          function 2;          function 3;")
for i in range(10):
  print(timeit.timeit('return_change_in_list1(list1,list2)', globals=globals(), number=1000), end='; ')
  print(timeit.timeit('return_change_in_list2(list1,list2)', globals=globals(), number=1000), end='; ')
  print(timeit.timeit('return_change_in_list3(list1,list2)', globals=globals(), number=1000), end=';\n')
print("\n\nfunction 4;          function 5")
for i in range(10):  
  print(timeit.timeit('return_change_in_list4(list1,list2)', globals=globals(), number=1000), end='; ')
  print(timeit.timeit('return_change_in_list5(list1,list2)', globals=globals(), number=1000))
```

One of the outputs, in my computer:

```
function 1;          function 2;          function 3;
4.1352741499999865; 7.948646284999995; 6.719404378000036;
3.991087896999943; 7.604543525999816; 7.098497474999931;
4.010241690999919; 7.593738104000295; 7.702650748999986;
4.19843784700015; 7.672624406000068; 7.5358697430001484;
4.14458595699989; 9.280372852000255; 8.256589966999854;
4.391348879000361; 7.764564555000106; 7.068202192999706;
4.2762628720001885; 8.209926066000207; 6.952296369000123;
3.8595704109998223; 11.935936167999898; 16.16772019300015;
8.138206416999765; 12.870063486000163; 15.746456568000212;
7.82583780899995; 11.736876751000182; 8.441530435000004;


function 4;          function 5
3.098060323000027; 2.7393256840000504
2.7861139729998285; 2.548324536000109
2.5771596439999485; 2.5661135760001343
2.7238574630000585; 2.594752339000024
2.6554647250000016; 2.8191915849997713
2.6247645640000883; 2.84076504199993
3.3453383609999037; 2.874788166000144
2.934053877000224; 2.950007811999967
5.239812221999728; 5.56969765399981
6.443700938999882; 4.463028083000154
```

When I changed the value of the lists to:

```py
list1=[i for i in range(20000)]+[10001]
list2=[i for i in range(20000)]+[1]
```

The output was:

```
function 1;          function 2;          function 3;
7.649340118000055; 7.448747982999976; 6.952490765999755;
7.988774744000239; 7.504327044999627; 6.845772889999807;
8.663970897000127; 7.184423781000078; 6.306836058000044;
8.560694254999817; 9.84430615500014; 7.21160759400027;
9.264006450000124; 10.213202504000037; 6.9900130920000265;
8.118536243000108; 7.994644583000081; 8.72104606899984;
9.391442627000288; 10.152986846000204; 9.21849292800016;
12.79642554100019; 18.673425052999846; 9.258570297000006;
9.084169438000117; 7.639437806999922; 6.252692509000099;
8.07683060699992; 8.637334575000295; 6.861809983000057;


function 4;          function 5
5.401317727999867; 5.694436690000202
5.218023895999977; 5.176447093999741
5.217633329999899; 6.5157359929999075
5.668167091000214; 5.585341486999823
5.535178367999833; 5.495608334000281
5.182497067999975; 5.231392088000121
5.375581145000069; 5.422244396000224
6.115360925999994; 6.473182661999999
6.920992358000149; 5.24543598199989
5.399142923999989; 5.373359425000217
```

And when I changed the value of the lists to:

```py
list1=[10001]+[i for i in range(20000)]
list2=[1]+[i for i in range(20000)]
```

The output was:

```
function 1;          function 2;          function 3;
0.0009529700000712182; 6.419712152000102; 6.169585547999759;
0.0013693759997295274; 6.107828072999837; 7.524482284999976;
0.0012241990002621606; 6.5767201450003085; 6.710827992999839;
0.0014647069997408835; 7.1059040999998615; 7.801625528999921;
0.002128201000232366; 9.78993420400002; 11.612126786999852;
0.0013582339997810777; 8.097604090000004; 7.4285691270001735;
0.0017677549999461917; 7.782655680000062; 6.897861279999688;
0.0014854589999231393; 6.621780061000209; 6.887953365999692;
0.0013960719998067361; 6.920186684999862; 6.5975830910001605;
0.0014639700002589962; 7.075127180999971; 6.68892119200018;


function 4;          function 5
0.000932528000248567; 0.0016549910001231183
0.0010366090000388795; 0.0016346869997505564
0.000914027999897371; 0.0015974439997989975
0.001006645999950706; 0.0018295350000698818
0.0010002259996326757; 0.001662419999775011
0.0009906569998747727; 0.0016710579998289177
0.0011088470000686357; 0.0016620189999230206
0.0010634639997988415; 0.0018417569999655825
0.0008912280000004102; 0.001735908000227937
0.0009644479996495647; 0.0015510050002376374
```

Note that different lists lead to different run times, different [`range`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=range+python&t=hp&ia=about)'s may also affect the result, try timing it by yourself!

It seems that the functions 4 and 5 are the fastest of these five.

> [List comprehensions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=list+comprehension+python&t=hp&ia=web) need to iterate over the entire `list_a` and `list_b`. There are lots of wasted computation when only the first element is needed." - [GZ0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57222450/10876117)

That's true, functions 4 and 5 seem the way to go. :)

Note that function 4 is based on the [Jab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225020/jab)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57222144/10876117), while function 5 is based on the [GZ0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57222450/10876117)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57222450/edit) and [Jab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225020/jab)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57222144/10876117). This answer took me a lot of time but I think it was worth it.

Comment: list comprehension doesn't speed up the existing process

Comment: The approach of the author assumes both lists have the same length.

Comment: List comprehensions need to iterate over the entire `list_a` and `list_b`. There are lots of wasted computation when only the first element is needed.

Comment: Actually, I just realize the above comment does not apply to the specific input in your tests, where the changed element happens to occur in the last place. For that input, functions 1, 2 and 3 are slower probably due to (1) the overhead of list construction and (2) explicit index-based list accesses are slower than `zip`.

Comment: You are right, the change should not happen in the end... I am going to change that.

Comment: You can add another input while keeping the previous one to demonstrate different causes of speedups.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if each element for each iteration is the same Also `itertools.zip_longest` will ensure iteration until at least the smallest list is exhausted

```
list_a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
list_b = [1,2,3,4,999,6,7,8]

def find_diff(list_a, list_b):
  for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b):
    if a != b:
      return b
  return None


print(find_diff(list_a, list_b))
```

This returns `999`. If all elements are the same then returns `None`

This can also be done using `next` as GZO stated, as it's the same logic as mine. But I'd use `None` as a default.

```
next((b for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b) if a != b), None)
```

Comment: Edited to return `b` when they differ. Also if both list's always have same length then don't need `zip_longest`

Answer (score 0):

```
next(b for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b) if a != b)
```

Comment: Don't you mean `next(b for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b) if a != b)`